# How to implement shortcut commands to the "Share > Email" under contextual menu?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut-menu

How to implement shortcut commands to the "Share > Email" under contextual menu in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

The New Email With Selection service is basically the same, but it's available in more applications and views.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it only works if you highlight the file as text selection, not as file selection. So it grabs the text of the file into Apple Mail instead as a whole file attachment. That's lame or it could be a bug. Well, Mountain Lion is still in its first release, I hope Apple fixes that one on the next 10.8.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service for that using Automator. The following screenshots show you what to do:

[image: Create a service]

[image: Set service parameters]

Pay attention "Service receives" part.

Than save a service and activate it as in the post above. This will go into "Services" (not to "Share") though.